# How to output different files using a macro?

Tags: r, csv, macros

I have a big R file, which I will use to analyze ten data files, corresponding to the ten subjects I ran in my study. 
Let's say the ten data files are named `sub1.csv`, `sub2.csv` etc.

The R file outputs a few tables in `csv` format and a few graphs in `PDF` format (about ten or fifteen outputs in total).

Once I will have all the outputs I need to compare them, so it would be nice to have each output file named after the subject, for example:

```
graph1_sub1.pdf
graph2_sub1.pdf
table1_sub1.csv
```

and so on for all files for each subject.

I was wondering, what is the best workflow to obtain all the output files named after each subjects?

I thought about creating ten different R files, but then I have to rewrite the output files names for every single subject (even though with the search function it should not take long). I was wondering if there is a better way, maybe using a macro.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough specifics to give a really good answer but it is possible to write files in a loop. One thing I've ended up doing often is subletting data in different ways and creating plots or exporting the data. You can loop through i %in% (# of files) and then paste together the file names like paste0("graph1_",i,".pdf")

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean I should do something like a for loop, looping over the entire R file? Could you please write the code of the first line of the for loop, I got what you mean but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Here's a start: `for(i in names(x)){
  write_csv(x[[i]], paste0(i,"file.csv"), col_names = FALSE)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your request, here's an example of generating plots and exporting through a loop:

```
for(s in unique(iris$Species)){

  temp = iris[iris$Species == s,]

  pdf(file = paste0(s,"_width_hist.pdf"))
  hist(temp$Sepal.Width)
  dev.off()

  pdf(file = paste0(s,"_length_hist.pdf"))
  hist(temp$Sepal.Length)
  dev.off()

  write.csv(x = temp, file = paste0(s,".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

This is definitely simpler than what you're doing but you *can* use loops like this to generate files. Another option would be to write a function that generates all the desired output from one data set and use `lapply` to run it on all the data sets.